# Scrolling a ListView - screen height detection needed

Tags: xaml

I am working on a WinRT app which contains a listview. The Listview has grown recently and I need to put a vertical scrollbar around it.
So far I have hardcoded the height in the Grid to 500.
However I want to know how to set the height to detect how much space is available. This may vary depending on the device being used. How do I do that?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="500"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="*" FontSize="40" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Red"/>
        <TextBlock Text=" = Required " FontSize="20"/>   
    </StackPanel>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
    <ListView 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Survey.SelectedSection.Questions, Mode=TwoWay}"
        IsSwipeEnabled="False"
        SelectionMode="None"
        Background="White"
        ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ResourceKey=QuestionDisplay}"
        ItemContainerStyle=
            "{StaticResource ResourceKey=QuestionListViewItemContainerStyle}" />
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: ListView already has a ScrollViewer embedded in it's template. Just get rid of the parent ScrollViewer you have on there now and set your second row height to `Height="*"` and it will invoke since it's set to `Auto` by default.

Comment: ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility is Auto by default. If it's not invoking the scroll then my next question would be, are there parent containers that this Grid is a child of, like StackPanel? Because that sort of thing would also cause it to not invoke scrolling.

Comment: You are right. There was a stackpanel parent and now I have got rid of it, it works. So thank you for that.

Comment: Cool, ya that's a common one in layout issues. I guess you could either del the question or I could poach some easy points before another person does lol. Either way glad you got your remedy.

Comment: I am happy to tick you the answer if you want. I am new to XAML and I am about to ask another simple question, so keep a lookout. And thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So like we discussed. `ListView` has a `ScrollViewer` alread embedded in its template. The reason it would invoke scrolling with a fixed height as opposed to naturally was a fixed boundary was provided to invoke it.

By adjusting your layout so that it's parent panel (and up the parent tree) didn't include `StackPanel` and using `Grid` instead with star `*` sizing it allowed a boundary to invoke it as desired. The reason for this is whereas `StackPanel` will only consume the space required, regardless of the space available. A `Grid` will consume whatever space is provided while restricting its children in its layout providing that boundary necessary to invoke the scrolling of the embedded `ScrollViewer` which has the attached property of `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility` set to `Auto` by default.

Glad you found your fix, welcome to the wonderful world of XAML which once you get used to it, you'll generally find is a lot easier to work with than it's cousin HTML. Cheers :)

Comment: You are probably right about XAML although it seems very verbose. I have been doing web development for so long so it will take a while I think before I prefer XAML

Comment: Ya I hear ya, I work with both daily on an enterprise level and I have to say, XAML > HTML any day of the week when included with all the added functionality provided by platforms like wpf, uwp, etc. Except I get how it can be a familiarity vote until you've really dived deep into both.